# How to extract the shape value of a placeholder Tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I defined a `x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])` for input data. Later on, I need to know the first value of the shape of `x` as batch size. And I extract the value by `x.get_shape().as_list()[0]` but I got `None`. Could you please tell me how should I extract it properly? Thanks a lot!

Edit:

I have used `tf.get_shape()` now but it cause another bug. In my code, I have defined a `deconv` funciton:

```
def deconv(X, W, b, output_shape):
    X += b 
    return tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(X, W, output_shape, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1])
```

If I set the `batch_size` to a `int` in such way: `batch_size = 50`, the calling of the `deconv` functions works well as following:

```
W_conv2_T = tf.ones([5, 5, 32, 64])
pool1_tr = deconv(conv2_tr, W_conv2_T, tf.zeros([64]), [batch_size, 14, 14, 32])
```

The shape of `conv2_tr` is `[50, 14, 14, 64]`. And the resulting shape of `pool1_tr` is `[50, 14, 14, 32]`. But if I set `batch_size = tf.get_shape(x)[0]`, shape of `conv2_tr` is `[None, 14, 14, 64]` and the resulting shape of `pool1_tr` becomes `[None, None, None, None]`. This bug is so strange. Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A value of `None` for the number of rows in your placeholder means that it can vary at runtime, so you must use [`tf.shape(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) to get the shape as a `tf.Tensor`. The following code should work:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately I got another related strange bug and I have no idea about that. I have edited the question and add the further information. Could you please take a look and help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the shape inference for `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose()` is pretty weak. (And it looks like I wrote it :P.) Thanks for drawing it to our attention - we'll prepare a fix and in the meantime you can call `pool1_tr.set_shape()` with the known dimensions of that shape.